# Convert summary data (cumulative cases) to daily cases pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have case data that is presented as a time series. They are summed for each following day, what can be used to turn them into daily case count data?

My dataframe in pandas:

```
    data         sum_cases (cumulative)
0   2020-05-02   4.0
1   2020-05-03   21.0
2   2020-05-04   37.0
3   2020-05-05   51.0
```

I want them to look like this:

```
    data         sum_cases(cumulative)    daily_cases
0   2020-05-02   4.0                      4.0
1   2020-05-03   21.0                     17.0
2   2020-05-04   37.0                     16.0
3   2020-05-05   51.0                     14.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If indeed your DF has has the data in date order, then you might be able to get away with:

```
df['daily_cases'] = df['sum_cases'] - df['sum_cases'].shift(fill_value=0)
```

Comment: (just be wary if you've got gaps - and there's better approaches if you can have your DF use a unique datetime index anyway... (and if you're generally doing time series analysis - that's generally preferred))